# How to make the index view retrieve/output data in the order submitted in the posting form?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

Using a nested form, I create a post which is ordered `Text1`, `Url1`, `Text2`.

However, when I retrieve this data (controller Index action) and display it in the view (`index.html.erb`) it displays as `Text1`, `Text2`, `Url1`. How can I get it to display in the view with the original order I gave it in the nested posting form?

Your help would be amazing - I just can't make this work!

Nested Form:
[image: Nested Form http://imgur.com/b7lSbSt]

Browser:
[image]

Post Model

```
  class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :texts
   has_many :urls 
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :texts, :urls
  end
```

Text Model

```
  class Text < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :post 
  end
```

Url Model

```
  class Url < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :post
  end
```

Schema

```
 create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.datetime "created_at", null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 end

 create_table "texts", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.text     "textattr"
   t.datetime "created_at", null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
   t.integer  "post_id"
 end

 add_index "texts", ["post_id"], name: "index_texts_on_post_id"

 create_table "urls", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string   "urlattr"
   t.datetime "created_at", null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
   t.integer  "post_id"
 end

 add_index "urls", ["post_id"], name: "index_urls_on_post_id"
```

Posts Controller

```
 class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @posts = Post.includes(:texts, :urls).all.order(created_at: :desc)
  end

  def show
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])
   @texts = @post.texts 
   @urls = @post.urls 
   @photos = @post.photos 
  end 

  def new
    @post = Post.new 
  end 

  def create
   @post = Post.new(post_params) 
    if @post.save 
     redirect_to @post
    else 
     render 'new'
    end 
  end


   private 
    def post_params 
        params.require(:post).permit(:texts_attributes => [:textattr], :urls_attributes => [:urlattr], :photos_attributes => [:image])
     end 
 end
```

View (Index.html.erb)

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %> 

 <% post.texts.each do |text|%>
  <%= text.textattr %> <br> 
 <% end %>

 <% post.urls.each do |url|%>
  <%= url.urlattr %> <br> 
 <% end %> 

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to `Pavan`'s answer, your model structure is flawed.

You are trying to pull combined data through two separate models. By virtue of the fact you're expecting them to be present in both instances, I'd say put them into a single model:

```
#app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :meta, class_name: "Meta"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :meta
end

#app/models/meta.rb
class Meta < ActiveRecord::Base
  #id | text | url | created_at | updated_at
  belongs_to :post
end
```

This way, you'll get:

```
@posts.each do |post|
  post.meta.each do |meta|
    meta.try(:text)
    meta.try(:url)
  end
end
```

---

The migration for the above will be:

```
 create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.datetime "created_at", null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 end

 create_table "metas", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.text     "text"
   t.string   "url"
   t.datetime "created_at", null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
   t.integer  "post_id"
 end
```

Comment: Hi Richard - thanks for your feedback. Unfortunately, this doesn't work for other permutations. For instance, posting Text1 Url1 Url2 Text2 in the form, results in Text1 Url1 Text2 Url2 in the browser display :/

Comment: Hi Richard, I know this isn't conventional, but I just can't get my head around this issue. I've posted another question and rectified any ambiguity. If there was any chance you could have a look and help me out I'd really really appreciate it!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35455261/how-to-get-the-output-of-a-nested-form-to-stay-in-its-exact-original-order-desp

Comment: Certainly, let me take a look for you