# How to get the output of a nested form to stay in its exact original order, despite permutations, using the index action & index template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I am using a nested form to post Urls and Texts. Via javascript, I am allowing any permutation of these two fields e.g. Url1 Text1 Text2 Url2 or Url1 Text1 Url2 Text2 etc

[image: http://imgur.com/DBPPZBf]

After submitting the form and redirecting to the index.html.view, I am then trying to keep the original order of whatever permutation I decide to use in the form i.e. if I decided to post Text1 Url1 Url2 Text2 Url3 I need that exact same arrangement to display in the browser.

Post Form Code

[image: http://imgur.com/dtjZrFX]

Post Model

```
 class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :texts
   has_many :urls    
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :texts, :urls 
 end
```

Text Model

```
 class Text < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post 
 end
```

Url Model

```
 class Url < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
 end
```

Schema

```
 ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160215123916) do

 create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

 create_table "texts", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.text     "textattr"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.integer  "post_id"
 end

 add_index "texts", ["post_id"], name: "index_texts_on_post_id"

 create_table "urls", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "urlattr"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.integer  "post_id"
 end

 add_index "urls", ["post_id"], name: "index_urls_on_post_id"

end
```

Posts Controller

```
  class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @posts = Post.includes(:texts, :urls).all.order(created_at: :desc)
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new 
   end 

  def create
   @post = Post.new(post_params) 
    if @post.save 
      redirect_to '/posts'
    else 
      render 'new'
    end 
  end

   private 
    def post_params 
        params.require(:post).permit(:texts_attributes => [:textattr], :urls_attributes => [:urlattr])
    end 
 end
```

Index.html.erb (Unsuccessful Attempt)

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %> 

<% post.texts.each do |text|%>
 <%= text.textattr %> <br> 
<% end %>

<% post.urls.each do |url|%>
 <%= url.urlattr %> <br> 
<% end %> 

<% end %>
```

Index.html.erb (Unsuccessful Attempt)

```
   <% @posts.each do |post| %> 

    <% [post.texts, post.urls].flatten.sort_by { |c| [c.created_at] }.each do |content| %>
      <% if content.class.name == "Text" %>
        <%= content.textattr %> 
      <% elsif content.is_a? Url %>
         <%= content.urlattr %> 
      <% end %> 
    <% end %>

  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Richard says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35457209/147180), you need to add an `order` column (or `position` - calling the column `order` can cause confusion with the generated SQL).

I think the main issue is your [coffeescript code](https://github.com/dompburford/anotherone/blob/6e4aa31337c19c20b07698e88cb42811a31bbbd8/app/assets/javascripts/posts.coffee). You need to generate a hidden input with each row you add, and use a single `current_index` counter for row you add:

```
current_index = 0

addText = ->
 html = """
 <br>
  <textarea name="post[things_attributes][#{current_index}][text]" id="post_things_attributes_#{current_index}_text"></textarea>
  <input type="hidden" name="post[things_attributes][#{current_index}][order]" id="post_things_attributes_#{current_index}_order" value="#{current_index}" />
 """

 $("#new_post input[type='submit']").before(html)
 current_index += 1

addUrl = ->
 html = """
 <br>
  <input type="url" name="post[things_attributes][#{current_index}][url]" id="post_things_attributes_#{current_index}_url">
  <input type="hidden" name="post[things_attributes][#{current_index}][order]" id="post_things_attributes_#{current_index}_order" value="#{current_index}" />
 """

 $("#new_post input[type='submit']").before(html)
 current_index += 1
```

In your `index.html.erb`, order the `Things` by the `order` column:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <% post.things.order(:order).each do |thing| %>
    <br>
    <%= thing.try(:text) %>
    <%= thing.try(:url) %>
  <% end %>

  <br>
<% end %>
```

---

It's also worth noting that this dynamic nested form pattern is very well-handled by the [cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon). I'd recommend taking a look and using that in your project.

Answer (score 1):

As per my previous answer, you definitely need to put your `texts` and `urls` objects into a single table/model. This will allow you to assign "order" values for them.

---

I would add an `order` value to the `texts` / `urls` and then use the [`child_index`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for#512-Setting-child-index-while-using-nested-attributes-mass-assignment) value to populate it:

```
#app/views/posts/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :meta do |t| %>
    <%= t.text_field :textattr %>
    <%= t.hidden_field :order, t.index %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

According to the docs:

> When a collection is used you might want to know the `index` of each object into the array. For this purpose, the `index` method is available in the `FormBuilder` object.
>
> ```
> <%= form_for @person do |person_form| %>
>   ...
>   <%= person_form.fields_for :projects do |project_fields| %>
>     Project #<%= project_fields.index %>
>     ...
>   <% end %>
>   ...
> <% end %>
> ```

--

This will allow you to pass the `order` attribute through to your db:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.new post_params
    @post.save
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(meta_attributes: [:order, :textattr])
  end
end
```

---

**Update**

I just tried this approach and can confirm it works (`index`):

[image]

[image]

The only thing I would say is that you might not have an `order` column in your model, although it should not come back with the merge error.

I notice you're using outdated javascript code, can you try without using that code and see what happens?

Comment: Hi Richard - You are a true hero! I created a single table with a Url column, Text column, as well as an Order column (type integer). However, when I add the line "<%= t.hidden_field :order, t.index %>" it comes up with this error in the console referencing that line: "undefined method `merge' for nil:NilClass" - not quite sure how to proceed...

Comment: Interesting, can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Okay so you do have an `order` attribute - have you used `accepts_nested_attributes_for` from `Post accepts_nested_attributes_for :things`?

Comment: Is there any way we could use Skype (username dom.burford) or a more instant communication? Unfortunately, my reputation is too low to move to chat on SO.

Comment: my email is peckrich@gmail.com if you want to chat on there?